# Why does document.querySelectorAll return a StaticNodeList rather than a real Array?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

It bugs me that I can't just do `document.querySelectorAll(...).map(...)` even in Firefox 3.6, and I still can't find an answer, so I thought I'd cross-post on SO the question from this blog:

http://blowery.org/2008/08/29/yay-for-queryselectorall-boo-for-staticnodelist/

Does anyone know of a technical reason why you don't get an Array?  Or why a StaticNodeList doesn't inherit from an Array in such a way that you could use `map`, `concat`, etc?

(BTW if it's just one function you want, you can do something like `NodeList.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map;`...but again, why is this functionality (intentionally?) blocked in the first place?)

Comment: Actually also getElementsByTagName does not return an Array, but a collection, and if you want to use it like an Array (with methods like concat etc.) you have to convert such collection into an Array by doing a loop and copy each element of the collection into an Array. Nobody ever complained about this.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I believe it to be a philosophical decision of the W3C. The design of the W3C DOM [spec] is quite orthogonal to the design of JavaScript, as the DOM is *meant* to be platform and language neutral.

Decisions like "`getElementsByFoo()` returns an ordered `NodeList`" or "`querySelectorAll()` returns a `StaticNodeList`" are very much intentional, so that implementations don't have to worry about aligning their returned data structure based on language-dependent implementations (like `.map` being available on Arrays in JavaScript and Ruby, but *not* on Lists in C#).

The W3C aim low: they'll say a `NodeList` should contain a [readonly `.length` property of type unsigned long](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) because they believe every implementation can at least support *that*, but they won't say explicitly that the `[]` index operator should be overloaded to support getting positional elements, because they don't want to stymie some poor little language that comes along that wants to implement `getElementsByFoo()` but cannot support operator overloading. It's a prevalent philosophy present throughout much of the spec.

John Resig has [voiced a similar option](http://ejohn.org/blog/unimpressed-by-nodeiterator/) as yours, to which [he adds](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8ty7l/john_resig_thinks_binary_flags_are_crazy/c0af9xv):

> My argument isn't so much that
>   `NodeIterator` isn't very DOM-like it's
>   that it isn't very JavaScript-like. It
>   doesn't take advantage of the features
>   present in the JavaScript language and
>   use them to the best of its ability...

I do somewhat empathize. If the DOM was written specifically with JavaScript features in mind it would be a lot less awkward and more intuitive to use. At the same time I do understand the W3C's design decisions.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me make sense of the situation.

Comment: @Kev: I saw your comment on that blog article page questioning how you would go about converting the `StaticNodeList` to an array. I would endorse @mck89's answer as the way to go for converting a `NodeList`/`StaticNodeList` to a native Array, but that will fail in IE (8 obv) with a JScript error, since those objects are hosted/"special".

Comment: True, that's why I upvoted him.  Someone else has cancelled my +1 though.  What do you mean by hosted/special?

Comment: @Kev: hosted variables are any variables provided by the "host" environment (eg a web browser). For example `document`, `window`, etc. IE often implements these "specially" (for example as COM objects) that sometimes don't conform to normal usage, in small and subtle ways, such as `Array.prototype.slice.call` bombing when given a `StaticNodeList` ;)

Answer (score 310):

You can use ES2015 (ES6) [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

`[...document.querySelectorAll('div')]`

will convert StaticNodeList to Array of items.

Here is an example on how to use it.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].map(x => console.log(x.innerHTML))
```

```html
<div>Text 1</div>
<div>Text 2</div>
```

Comment: Another way is to use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from): `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).map(x => console.log(x.innerHTML))`

Comment: works great, but this answer is a odd way to use map

Comment: Also note that `Array.from()` takes a mapping function as its second parameter. Very useful to avoid a second iteration (it lets you map the array while it's still under construction, so there is just one iteration). Quoting from MDN: More clearly, `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)` has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`, except that it does not create an intermediate array, and `mapFn` only receives two arguments (element, index) without the whole array, because the array is still under construction.

Answer (score 43):

I don't know why it returns a node list instead of an array, maybe because like getElementsByTagName it will update the result when you update the DOM. Anyway a very simple method to transform that result in a simple array is:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(...));
```

and then you can do:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(...)).map(...);
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't update the result when you update the DOM--hence 'static'.  You have to manually call qSA again to update the result.  +1 for the `slice` line though.

Comment: Yeah, like Kev said: qSA resultset is static, getElementsByTagName() resultset is dynamic.

Comment: IE8 only supports querySelectorAll() in standards mode

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to what Crescent said,

> if it's just one function you want, you can do something like NodeList.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map

**Don't do this!** It's not at all guaranteed to work.

No JavaScript or DOM/BOM standard specifies that the `NodeList` constructor-function even exists as a global/`window` property, or that the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` will inherit from it, or that its prototype is writable, or that the function `Array.prototype.map` will actually work on a NodeList.

A NodeList is allowed to be a ‘host object’ (and is one, in IE and some older browsers). The `Array` methods are defined as being allowed to operate on any JavaScript ‘native object’ that exposes numeric and `length` properties, but they're not required to work on host objects (and in IE, they don't).

It's annoying that you don't get all the array methods on DOM lists (all of them, not just StaticNodeList), but there's no reliable way round it. You'll have to convert every DOM list you get back to an Array manually:

```
Array.fromList= function(list) {
    var array= new Array(list.length);
    for (var i= 0, n= list.length; i<n; i++)
        array[i]= list[i];
    return array;
};

Array.fromList(element.childNodes).forEach(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I agree +1. Just a comment, I think doing "var array = []" instead of "var array = new Array(list.length)" wouild make the code even shorter. But I'm interested if you know there might be a problem in doing this.

Comment: @MarcoDemaio: No, no problem. `new Array(n)` just gives the JS terp a hint on how long the array's going to end up. That could allow it to allocate that amount of space in advance, which would potentially result in a speedup as some memory reallocations could be avoided as the array grows. I don't know if it actually helps in modern browsers though... I would suspect not measurably.

Comment: Now it's implemented in [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 13):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(...)).map(...)
```

Not available on IE11 though https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_from

Comment: While this may not exactly answer the *why* question posed by OP ... it is still a valid, pragmatic, and concise solution to the problem the OP faces and worked well for me too. Many other posts talk about overriding the `Element` prototype which is dangerous. I would use this solution instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simply do following

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(...), function(...){...});
```

It works perfect for me

Answer (score -1):

This is an option I wanted to add to the range of other possibilities suggested by others here. It's meant for intellectual fun only and is **not advised**.

---

Just for the *fun* of it, here's a way to "force" `querySelectorAll` to kneel down and bow to you:

```
Element.prototype.querySelectorAll = (function(QSA){
    return function(){
        return [...QSA.call(this, arguments[0])]
    }
})(Element.prototype.querySelectorAll);
```

Now it feels good to step all over that function, showing it who's the boss.
Now I don't know what's better, creating a whole new **named** function wrapper and then have all your code use that weird name (pretty much jQuery-style) or override the function like above once so the rest of your code would still be able to use the original DOM method name `querySelectorAll`.

- Such approach would eliminate possible use of [sub-methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#Methods)

> I wouldn't recommend this in any way, unless you honestly don't give a [you know what].