# why Array.prototype.map.call instead of Array.map.call

Tags: javascript

I fell upon some lines of code where the guy uses `Array.prototype.map.call` instead of `Array.map.call`:

```
function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}
```

Why not simply calling `Array.map.call`? I checked on the Firefox console and both `Array` and `Array.prototype` have the map function. Is there a difference ?

Comment: On the other hand, if you can guarantee that `Array.map` is available by default, you can also do `function getLinks() { return [link.href for (link of document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a')]; }`. :)

Comment: It should be noted that this is taken from a CasperJS crawler example. So there's no need to worry about cross-browser compatability.

Answer (score 38):

This is because `document.querySelectorAll` does not return an `Array` instance but an instance of `NodeList` (or at least is not guaranteed to return an `Array` on all browsers).
`NodeList` has indexed elements but does not include all methods from the `Array` prototype.

This is why we need a hack calling `map` method from `Array`'s prototype in the context of the returned object.

I assume that you understand that for:

```
var a = [], f = function() {};
```

the expression:

```
a.map(f);
```

is equivalent to:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(a, f);
```

*See also*:

- [Why does document.querySelectorAll return a StaticNodeList rather than a real Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600343/1010868)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 9):

**Because `Array.map.call` doesn't work.**  `Array.map` is built to accept two parameters: the array, and the callback.  `call` runs a function setting its `this` to the object you supply.

So, when you run `Array.prototype.map.call(somearray,function(){...});` it is virtually the same as if you called `somearray.map(function(){...});`.  `Array.map` is just a utility method Javascript **in Firefox only** (another reason why not to use it) has to make life easier.  The `Array.map` function is not cross-browser.

**Edit:** The reason that they had to use `Array.prototype.map.call(links,...);` instead of just `links.map(...);`, is that `querySelectorAll` does not return a normal array, it returns a `NodeList` that does not have a `map` method.

Comment: Hi, you are wrong. The reason is `document.querySelectorAll` does not return `Array` instance. This is why we need a hack calling it from Array's prototype in context of returned object.

Comment: @TomaszGawel: Er, the question is about the difference between `Array.map.call` and `Array.prototype.map.call`, not between `Array.prototype.map.call` and calling `.map` directly. Or at least that’s what I got out of it.

Comment: @TomaszGawel: No, I mean `Array.map`. Try it on Firefox. Read this answer.

Comment: Bonus SpiderMonkey screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/4zLukZL.png (cf. http://i.imgur.com/8LUOfkk.png)

Answer (score 3):

Good Question:
Array is a constructor function to create arrays.

If you type Array in browser console you will get a function definition, something like
***function Array() { [native code] }***
While if you type Array.prototype in browser console you will get an empty array i.e **[ ]**
 i.e. an Array object.
Consider this excerpt

```
function a(){
console.log('hi');
function b(){console.log('b');}
function c(){console.log('c');}
return {b:b,c:c,d:this}
}
```

When you type `d = new a();`
Then d is an object having two properties which are functions i.e. b and c and you can call
`>> d.b()        //logs b` 
`>> d.c()        //logs c`
But you cannot call
`a.b() or a.c()`     // since function b and c is not property of a.
So just as function b and c are defined in function a. Similarly function map is defined in function Array.
So you cannot call `Array.map()` but you have to get an object of Array and call map function on it. 
 `Array.prototype` gives us an Array object
Therefore they are using `Array.prototype.map.call(a,func)`

Sorry for long explanation. Hope it benefits.:)

Answer (score 1):

`map` is meant to be called on array instances. Thus, `Array.prototype.map`. `Array.map` doesn't exist in most browsers.