# js: why use Array.prototype.map.call instead of map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is an exract from casperjs JS :

```
function getPrices() {
  var price = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(price, function(elem) {
    return elem.textContent;
  });
}
```

Why use Array.prototype.map.call: wouldn't be possible to use simply: 
`price.map()`  ?

Comment: Try it and you'll see that `price` has no method `map`…

Comment: document.querySelectorAll does't return actual array, it returns array like structure.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20154246/2025201)

Comment: Almost a duplicate. The ANSWER is the same as for the duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `price` is an array-like(NodeList) object, not an array.

With `Array.prototype.map`, you are taking a method of Array and use the array-like object as object for mapping.

Comment: And therefore `price` itself has no `map` method. That's why `Array.prototype.map.call` is needed

Comment: yes. basically you borrow the method from Array.

Answer (score 1):

> Why use Array.prototype.map.call: wouldn't be possible to use simply: 
>   price.map() ?

Because you want to call the function you pass in the call as a second argument with a specified `this`. The `this` in your case is the first argument: `price`, The `price` is an array like object (it has a length property), but it hasn't the methods that arrays have. So the only way you could call the `map` function on an array like object is this.

If price would have been an array, you could call the map as usually:

```
price.map(function(item){//...});
```

The fact that it's not an array routes you to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.querySelectorAll` returns an *array-like* object which does not have `.map` method. It doesn't return actual *array*.