# explaining the differences between querySelectorAll and $$

Tags: javascript, jquery

correct me if i'm wrong, the double dollar sign ($$) is a shorthand for (querySelectorAll) in JavaScript.
but what i've notice in this code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#main')

NodeList[1]
0:section#main.group
length:1
__proto__:NodeList
```

that it return a nodelist 

and when i use:

```
 $$('#main')
Array[1]
0:section#main.group
length:1
__proto__:Array[0]
```

it return an array like obj 
so they aren't the same, right ?!!

One thing i'm not using jQuery so is the dollar sign originally part of javascript and jQuery just using it or its different ?!

Comment: i think $$ only works if you have implemented jquery. querySelectorAll is a plain javascript function

Comment: i didn't attach jQuery to my file and the result shown up is on chrome console   @mtizziani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the below snippet, `$$` is undefined.

It is a Command Line code by browser which works only when typed in console
where `document.querySelectorAll` works in both the `script` in page as well as console.

If you type

```
$$;
```

in console, it will return like this

> function $$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }

But if you type this,

```
document.querySelectorAll;
```

It will return

> function querySelectorAll() { [native code] }

`$$` is a function only for testing purpose like developer tools.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div'));
console.log($$('div'));
```

```html
<body>
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3</div>
</body>
```

Comment: ok, another questions didn't the console in the past used to return an html/xml format when you use document.querySelectorAll, now it return a Nodelist, even if i didn't use dir()

Comment: I think no. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600343/why-does-document-queryselectorall-return-a-staticnodelist-rather-than-a-real-ar
asked in 2010 and in it, the answer says that it returns a NodeList. so for last 7 years, there is no change I thing. I started to do a research on this. If I found something, will add it here

Comment: will I've watched i video on Lynda called    JavaScript : Enhancing The DOM [2013], and when he wrote  document.querySelectorAll in the console(chrome) he got an html code same is you write it in html doc,  and then he would use the dir() method to access it's properties as a node list

Comment: can you share the link to that video

Comment: if have access to lynda go to https://www.lynda.com/HTML-tutorials/Traversing-up-down-DOM-nodes/122462/137627-4.html,or i can take a screenshot

Comment: 404. ok i will check for the resource in someother site and will let you know

Comment: search in lynda Traversing up and down DOM nodes