# Take all values of an iteration list

Tags: javascript, html

How is it possible to take all values of an array/list into one line?

Example code of html:

```
<div class="projects">
   <span clas="project_title"> project1 </span>
   <span clas="project_title"> project2 </span>
</div>
```

If I want to take the values of span I have to use this

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.projects span.project_title')[0].textContent
```

---

Result:

> project1
>
> ---

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.projects span.project_title')[1].textContent
```

---

Result:

> project2
>
> ---

Is there any simple JS query in order to take this results without need to iterate into the the list?

Example Result:

> project1, project2
>
> ---

Comment: No, the list has to be iterated, in a way or another, to get the content of the items.

Comment: To add on what @Teemu said: nothing stops you from creating a small function which iterates the list and outputs it the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way get all them without iteration. But that iteration can be done under the hood. You can use **[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to get the `textContents`. In this case you need to iterate over the `HTMLElements`, which is done under the hood of **[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('div.projects span.project_title');
const texts = Array.prototype.map.call(spans, item => item.textContent);

console.log(texts);
```

```html
<div class="projects">
   <span class="project_title"> project1 </span>
   <span class="project_title"> project2 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Seen as your using new ESnext features, couldn't you do `Array.from` instead of `Array.prototype.map.call`?

Comment: @Keith why to do like that, why I need to create an extra array?

Comment: I am using `this`'s feature with `map`.

Comment: Good point,..  My idea was Array.from is just easier for people to understand, and the performance hit on the array create is not that great.

Comment: @Keith Generally you are right, One array creation is not a big job. I am   like to working with context. If you are familiar with context, so you will know about `apply`, `call`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you could do with [`Array.prototype.slice.call`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600343/why-does-document-queryselectorall-return-a-staticnodelist-rather-than-a-real-ar) method .And change the  span class attribute word with `class` .`Array#map` used to create the array .Then `join(',')` the array with `,`

```js
var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.projects span.project_title')).map(a => a.textContent);

console.log(a.join(','))
```

```html
<div class="projects">
   <span class="project_title"> project1 </span>
   <span class="project_title"> project2 </span>
</div>
```