# Count how many elements in dynamic row

Tags: javascript, css, grid-layout

When using [CSS Grid Layout](https://youtu.be/FEnRpy9Xfes) to dynamically arrange elements in rows the browser calculates how many items go in a row depending on the size of the viewport. I'm looking for a way using JavaScript to determine how many items are in each row at a given viewport size. My purpose is to fill the inevitable part empty row at the end.

For example, given the CSS and HTML listed below, and at a particular viewport size results in this layout:

[image: CSS Grid Layout Narrow, Dynamic Rows, Part Empty Last Row]

And at a wider viewport results in this layout:

[image: CSS Grid Layout Wide, Dynamic Rows, Part Empty Last Row]

Each have missing elements in the last row.

Having the maximum number of elements a row I can dynamically load more elements to fill in the last row so it's the same number as the rest.

---

Example CSS and HTML:

```css
<style>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

main {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
article {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  max-width: 10000px;
  margin: 0;
}
article {
  margin: 0;
}
.listings {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.listings {
  font-family: Avenir, Roboto, Helvetica, san-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
}
.listing {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
.listing > h1 {
  margin: 1rem 1rem 0;
}
.listing > div {
  margin: 0.25em 1rem 1rem;
}
.listing > img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  order: -1;
  align-self: center;
}

</style>
```

```html
<main class="listings">
    <article class="listing">
        <img src="images/computer.jpg">
        <h1>87,500</h1>
        <div>1008[3/2]0</div>
    </article>

    <article class="listing">
        <img src="images/computer.jpg">
        <h1>30,000</h1>
        <div>952[2/1]0</div>
    </article>

    <article class="listing">
        <img src="images/computer.jpg">
        <h1>70,000</h1>
        <div>1090[3/1]0</div>
    </article>

    <article class="listing">
        <img src="images/computer.jpg">
        <h1>11,000</h1>
        <div>828[2/1]2</div>
    </article>

    <article class="listing">
        <img src="images/computer.jpg">
        <h1>25,000</h1>
        <div>1484[2/1]0</div>
    </article>

    <article class="listing">
        <img src="images/computer.jpg">
        <h1>199,000</h1>
        <div>2160[3/2]0</div>
    </article>

    <article class="listing">
        <img src="images/computer.jpg">
        <h1>42,000</h1>
        <div>1509[3/2]0</div>
    </article>

    <article class="listing">
        <img src="images/computer.jpg">
        <h1>230,000</h1>
        <div>1885[3/2]0</div>
    </article>
</main>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043684/how-to-calculate-the-amount-of-flexbox-items-in-a-row/49046973#49046973

Comment: and what about when browser resize ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif There is a lot of complexity to the question you linked to, and therefore the answers. The use case I have here is an evenly aligned, minimally interactive grid of elements, somewhat closely spaced, and not expecting the user to resize the browser—which I think covers many use cases. And in the case the user does resize the browser it's no worse than it was without this example.

Comment: i know that's why it's a possible duplicate ;) i didn't close as duplicate ... but it's almost the same thing, so both question should be linked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`elem.getBoundingClientRect().left`**

The `elem.getBoundingClientRect().left` property can be used to get the number of dynamic rows in a CSS grid layout. Just loop through the `article` elements [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and compare the element's `getBoundingClientRect().left` value to the previous. The compared value will increase within each row then drop when starting in the next row. Count the increments until the first drop occurs to determine the number of elements in each row.

```js
var articles = document.querySelectorAll('article')
console.log(articles[0].getBoundingClientRect().left) // 16
console.log(articles[1].getBoundingClientRect().left) // 238.156
console.log(articles[2].getBoundingClientRect().left) // 460.312
console.log(articles[3].getBoundingClientRect().left) // 682.468
console.log(articles[4].getBoundingClientRect().left) // 904.625
console.log(articles[5].getBoundingClientRect().left) // 1126.78
console.log(articles[6].getBoundingClientRect().left) // 16
```

Therefore we just need to count the increases in value between the previous `left` value and the next and once it drops we have our row count.

---

Here using `call` to apply array method `reduce` on the NodeList. Using `reduce` to carry forward the each value to compare to the next value:

```js
var rowlen = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll('article'), function (prev, next) {
  if ( !prev[2] ) {
    var ret = next.getBoundingClientRect().left
    // if increasing, increment counter
    if ( !(prev[0] > -1 && ret < prev[1]) ) { prev[0]++ }
    else { prev[2] = 1 } // else stop counting
  }
  return [prev[0],ret, prev[2]] // [counter, elem, stop-counting]
}, [0,null,0])[0]
```

[Codesandbox.io "complete partial row" example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/z20zmvo3yl)

Or old-school JS, sporting a `for` loop nested in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
var rowlen = (function () {
  for ( var ii = 0, arts = document.querySelectorAll('article'), 
        len = arts.length, el = 0, ell = 0; 
      ii < len; ii++ ) {
    el = arts[ii].getBoundingClientRect().left
    if ( el > ell || 0 === ell ) { ell = el }
    else { return ii; }
  }
}())
```

[Codesandbox.io "drop partial row" example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/wq989w70p8)

Answer (score 0):

**`elem.clientWidth`**

This example uses the element property [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)  to calculate the number of elements in each row.

```js
var rowlength = Math.floor( // round down to account for some spacing
  document.body.clientWidth / // width of viewport divided by...
  document.querySelectorAll('article')[0].clientWidth // width of an element
)
```

This gives me the number of items in each row, except possibly the last row.

---

**Complete Last Row**

I know I've loaded 8 elements initially, so I can now calculate how many items I need to complete the last row:

```js
var numelementsloaded = 8
```

Alternately I can count the number of loaded elements:

```js
var numelementsloaded = document.querySelectorAll('article').length
```

The [modulus](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/finding-a-remainder-in-javascript) (division remainder) operator will give me the number of elements in the last row:

```js
var numelementslastrow = elementsloaded % rowlength
```

Now calculate the number of elements needed to complete last row:

```js
var numelementsneeded = rowlength - numelementslastrow
```

All together and compressed, with a bonus:

```js
var rowlength = Math.floor(document.body.clientWidth/document.querySelectorAll('article')[0].clientWidth)
var numelementsneeded = rowlength - (document.querySelectorAll('article').length % rowlength)

// and duplicating the first few elements to illustrate completing the last row
for ( var ii = 0; ii < numelementsneeded; ii++ ) {
  document.querySelector('main').appendChild(
    // here is where I'd pull in new items from the server
    document.querySelectorAll('article')[ii].cloneNode(true)
  )
}
```

And that completes the last row:

[Codesandbox.io "complete last row" example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9zln7y0zj)

---

**Drop Last Row**

Another, technically simpler, option is to—rather than add new items—drop all the items in the last, partial row:

```js
var rowlength = Math.floor(document.body.clientWidth/document.querySelectorAll('article')[0].clientWidth)
var numelementslastrow = document.querySelectorAll('article').length % rowlength

// and dropping the elements in the last row
for ( var ii = 0; ii < numelementslastrow; ii++ ) {
  document.querySelector('main').removeChild(
    document.querySelector('article:last-child')
  )
}
```

If the last row is full, it stays. For example, if there are 8 items and each row has 4 items, 8 mod 4 = 0, therefore the `for` loop does not execute.

[Codesandbox.io "drop partial row" example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/38xz24m921)

Comment: your calculation is not accurate ... you need to consider the grid-gap, you may have bad result in some cases

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think the `Math.floor` takes care of that. Can you give me an example of the grid-gap resulting in the wrong number of elements in a row with my answer?

Comment: it's simple, you make the grip gap big enough in the way that if we sum them all you have a width bigger than the width of an element ... in other words it's like you can place another element using all the gap of one row

Comment: @TemaniAfif That makes sense—thanks for pointing that out. However for the more closely aligned layouts in my example `Math.floor` alone is working for me at different viewport sizes.

Comment: it's working for you in this particular case, but it won't work in all the cases ... you may check the duplicate link i posted above and you will find more accurate ways that consider everything (margin,padding, etc)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I prefer the simplicity of the example I gave over the one you linked to, and if this works in the majority of cases I'm happy with that.

Comment: yes but when posting question/answer here you are targeting a large audience of users so your code need to be accurate and not only satisfy your needs. That's why am highlighting this part as even if you don't adjsut the code, people can still see  comments