# Elements grid arranging CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a scenario: when you click on a box, it shows a "long box" (full width) in the next row. The problem is that I get a gap after the clicked object.

Is it possible show the "long box" in the next row without changing the structure of the small boxes using CSS?
Link to jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/mhLv7zj1/](http://jsfiddle.net/mhLv7zj1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".box").click(function(){
      $(this).next('.open').toggleClass('toggled');
    });
    $(".open").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
    });
})
```

[image: visual example of the final grid state after clicking on a box]

Comment: here is the http://jsfiddle.net/mhLv7zj1/

Comment: Please read the reason you couldn't put the fiddle link in the question and fix it otherwise your question is off topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Kinda - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XVdVmg

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D! This is what i searched for:  https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XVdVmg

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` and `flex-basis` properties.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(this).next('.open').toggleClass('toggled');
  });
  $(".open").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
  });
})
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  background: blue;
  height: 80px;
  flex: 1 1 32%;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.open {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.toggled {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 66.5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="open"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option. You can remove all the `li class="open"` from your HTML and instead have this algorithm on each click:

- hide/remove any already `open` items
- [calculate the number of items in the flex row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043684/how-to-calculate-the-amount-of-flexbox-items-in-a-row) where the item that was clicked lives and its position
- then you'll know where to make the insertion, so: at the end of this row, dynamically insert an `open` item (style it in advance so that it takes up an entire row (`flex: 0 0 100%;`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the red boxes are siblings of the blue boxes so when you make them `display:block` they push the other content around. You need to make the red boxes children of the blue boxes and use relative positioning to achieve your desired result.

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');

boxes.forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', expand.bind(b));
});

function expand() {
  this.querySelector('.open').classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

div.open {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(100% + 1px);
  left: -1px;
  width: calc(300% + 4px);
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.visible {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <div class="open"></div> </li>
  <li> <div class="open"></div> </li>
  <li> <div class="open"></div> </li>
  <li> <div class="open"></div> </li>
  <li> <div class="open"></div> </li>
  <li> <div class="open"></div> </li>
  <li> <div class="open"></div> </li>
  <li> <div class="open"></div> </li>
</ul>
```

PS. This example isn't a perfect fixed replica of your code but it should get you on the right track.