# CSS going-around content flow

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

Is there a way to define a content flow in CSS using flex or other techniques such that content "zig zags" or goes around in this way:

```
 -----------------
|A > B > C > D > E|
|J < I < H < G < F|
 -----------------

 ---
|A H|
|B G|
|C F|
|D E|
 ---
```

Assume there are always 2 columns or rows. I could split the items in 2 and create 2 wrapping items around them, but I would like it to be more dynamic.

Basically, how do I make the first row flow to the right and the second flow to the left?

Comment: Yes with CSS Grid Layout, have a look here: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Comment: @Armel That is the answer. Write it as an answer, and put an example :)

Comment: Either use `CSS Grid` or use `Flex` with `flex-wrap`. Keep in mind that `css grid` is not fully supported yet by all browsers.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the grid flow doesn't automatically to a "back and forth" kind of layout.

Comment: I think you didn't notice that what i want is the first row to go from left to right and the second from right to left...

Comment: No, there isn't anything that flows like that with a simple property. One need to use e.g. `order` or similar, and if the content is dynamic, script is needed. Well, Flexbox has the `*-reverse` property, but how that can be used is based on how the markup looks like

Comment: @LGSON that's actually a good tip. The items are already generated by script, so setting the order property on the fly is easy.

Comment: @ecc Note that I updated previous comment some.

Comment: Yeah, the `order` property would be the way to go, or creating the other `row` or `column` and setting `flex-direction: row-reverse` or `column-reverse` although that might be more work than actually needed... see this, maybe it can help https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/aQjBdz

Comment: Is there a fixed number of child elements?

Comment: Nevermind, you said you want it dynamic.

Comment: As has been stated, this is not **possible** unless the number of child elements is known. Hence existing solutions are *not scalable*.

Comment: How do you plan to distribute the items evenly in two rows / columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution does not use JavaScript and somewhat scalable. I use `display: flex` so that I could use the `order` property.

The basic idea is to assign `order: 1` to the last item, `order: 2` to the second last item and so on. The first half of the items have `order: -1` and a pseudo element having `order: 0` is used as a separator. The tricky part is where you figure out the "first half" of items:

```css
.demo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #EEE;
}
.demo > * {
  margin: .5em;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: #0CF;
}

/*
 * the example work for a list of 20 elements
 * for additional elements extend the repeating selectors
 */

/* all items ordered backwards */

.demo > :nth-last-child(1)  { order: 1; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(2)  { order: 2; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(3)  { order: 3; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(4)  { order: 4; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(5)  { order: 5; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(6)  { order: 6; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(7)  { order: 7; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(8)  { order: 8; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(9)  { order: 9; }
.demo > :nth-last-child(10) { order: 10; }

/* first half items are source ordered */

.demo> :nth-child(-n+0):nth-last-child(n+1),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+1):nth-last-child(n+2),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+2):nth-last-child(n+3),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+3):nth-last-child(n+4),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+4):nth-last-child(n+5),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+5):nth-last-child(n+6),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+6):nth-last-child(n+7),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+7):nth-last-child(n+8),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+8):nth-last-child(n+9),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+9):nth-last-child(n+10),
.demo> :nth-child(-n+10):nth-last-child(n+11) {
  order: -1;
}

/* the separator uses flex-basis trick and ordered between the two halves */

.demo::after {
  content: "";
  flex-basis: 100%;
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

For two column layout, specify `flex-direction: column; height: 25em` on the parent (height must be fixed).

Comment: This solution is so crazy and I love it

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that a pure scalable CSS solution doesn't actually exist in order to achieve such thing so you will need some scripting to dynamically adjust some properties in order to obtain the needed layout.

If we suppose that all the elements have **the same width** we can identify the number of element per row and apply styles to the elements depending on the row.

Here is a basic example based on a code of this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49046973/8620333

```js
//total number of element
var n_t = $('.item').length;
//full width of element with margin
var w = $('.item').outerWidth(true);
//width of container without padding
var w_c = $('.grid').width();
//nb element per row
var nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w),n_t);
console.log(nb);
$('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(nb+1)+')').addClass('right');
$('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(2*nb+1)+')').removeClass('right');
$('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(3*nb+1)+')').addClass('right');
$('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(4*nb+1)+')').removeClass('right');

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
   //only the width of container will change
   w_c = $('.grid').width();
   nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w),n_t);
   $('.item').removeClass('right');   
  $('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(nb+1)+')').addClass('right');
  $('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(2*nb+1)+')').removeClass('right');
  $('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(3*nb+1)+')').addClass('right');
  $('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(4*nb+1)+')').removeClass('right');
});
```

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float:left;
  clear:right;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.item.right {
  float:right;
  clear:left;
  background:blue;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">J</div>
  <div class="item">K</div>
  <div class="item">L</div>
  <div class="item">M</div>
  <div class="item">N</div>
  <div class="item">O</div>
  <div class="item">P</div>
</div>
```

This example isn't a perfect one as we have issue with alignment but the idea is to apply floating property to rows by alternating rows. I only considered 4 rows but we can easily make it dynamic using a loop like below:

```js
//total number of element
var n_t = $('.item').length;
//full width of element with margin
var w = $('.item').outerWidth(true);
//width of container without padding
var w_c = $('.grid').width();
//nb element per row
var nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w),n_t);
for(var i=1;i<n_t;i++) {
if(i%2==1)
   $('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(i*nb+1)+')').addClass('right');
else
   $('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(i*nb+1)+')').removeClass('right');
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
   //only the width of container will change
   w_c = $('.grid').width();
   nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w),n_t);
   $('.item').removeClass('right');
  for(var i=1;i<n_t;i++) {
    if(i%2==1)
      $('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(i*nb+1)+')').addClass('right');
    else
      $('.item:nth-child(1n+'+(i*nb+1)+')').removeClass('right');
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float:left;
  clear:right;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.item.right {
  float:right;
  clear:left;
  background:blue;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">J</div>
  <div class="item">K</div>
  <div class="item">L</div>
  <div class="item">M</div>
  <div class="item">N</div>
  <div class="item">O</div>
  <div class="item">P</div>
</div>
```

To have better alignment, we can consider the use of CSS grid or flexbox but in this case we will need to adjust the order property of the elements.

With CSS grid:

```js
//total number of element
var n_t = $('.item').length;
//full width of element with margin
var w = $('.item').outerWidth(true);
//width of container without padding
var w_c = $('.grid').width();
//nb element per row
var nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w), n_t);
//nb rows
var nr = n_t / nb;
//order of element
var or = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
      $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('order', or++);
    }
  else
    for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
      $('.item').eq(nb * i + (nb - j - 1)).css('order', or++);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  //only the width of container will change
  w_c = $('.grid').width();
  nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w), n_t);
  nr = n_t / nb;
  or = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('order', or++);
      }
    else
      for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + (nb - j - 1)).css('order', or++);
      }
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, 80px);
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.item {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">J</div>
  <div class="item">K</div>
  <div class="item">L</div>
  <div class="item">M</div>
  <div class="item">N</div>
  <div class="item">O</div>
  <div class="item">P</div>
</div>
```

This method allow a better alignment but the last row isn't always good.

We can correct the last row by adjusting the last elements usgin `grid-column` like below:

```js
//total number of element
var n_t = $('.item').length;
//full width of element with margin
var w = $('.item').outerWidth(true);
//width of container without padding
var w_c = $('.grid').width();
//nb element per row
var nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w), n_t);
//nb rows
var nr = Math.ceil(n_t / nb);
//order of element
var or = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
      $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('order', or++);
    }
  else
    for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
      $('.item').eq(nb * i + (nb - j - 1)).css('order', or++);
      /*fix the last row*/
      if (i == (nr - 1)) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('grid-column', " " + (nb - j));
      }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  //only the width of container will change
  w_c = $('.grid').width();
  nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w), n_t);
  nr = Math.ceil(n_t / nb);
  $('.item').css('grid-column', 'auto');
  or = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('order', or++);
      }
    else
      for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + (nb - j - 1)).css('order', or++);
        /*fix the last row*/
        if (i == nr - 1) {
          $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('grid-column', " " + (nb - j));
        }
      }
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, 80px);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.item {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">J</div>
  <div class="item">K</div>
  <div class="item">L</div>
  <div class="item">M</div>
  <div class="item">N</div>
  <div class="item">O</div>
  <div class="item">P</div>
</div>
```

---

Flexbox can be more suitable for the second case (the column direction). We simply do the same thing as previously considering columns instead of rows:

```js
//total number of element
var n_t = $('.item').length;
//full height of element with margin
var w = $('.item').outerHeight(true);
//height of container without padding
var w_c = $('.grid').height();
//nb element per row
var nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w), n_t);
//nb rows
var nr = n_t / nb;
//order of element
var or = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
      $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('order', or++);
    }
  else
    for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
      $('.item').eq(nb * i + (nb - j - 1)).css('order', or++);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  //only the width of container will change
  w_c = $('.grid').height();
  nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w), n_t);
  nr = n_t / nb;
  or = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('order', or++);
      }
    else
      for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + (nb - j - 1)).css('order', or++);
      }
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  height:100vh;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:flex-start;
  align-content:flex-start;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.item {
  height: 80px;
  width:80px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">J</div>
  <div class="item">K</div>
  <div class="item">L</div>
  <div class="item">M</div>
  <div class="item">N</div>
  <div class="item">O</div>
  <div class="item">P</div>
</div>
```

There is also an alignment issue in some cases with the last column that we can fix by adjust margin:

```js
//total number of element
var n_t = $('.item').length;
//full height of element with margin
var w = $('.item').outerHeight(true);
//height of container without padding
var w_c = $('.grid').height();
//nb element per row
var nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w), n_t);
//nb rows
var nr = Math.ceil(n_t / nb);
//order of element
var or = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
      $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('order', or++);
    }
  else {
    for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
      $('.item').eq(nb * i + (nb - j - 1)).css('order', or++);
    }
    if (i == (nr - 1)) {
      /*we add margin+height of non-existing element*/
      $('.item:last').css('margin-top', ((nb * nr - n_t) * (80 + 10)) + "px")
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  //only the width of container will change
  w_c = $('.grid').height();
  nb = Math.min(parseInt(w_c / w), n_t);
  nr = Math.ceil(n_t / nb);
  or = 0;
  $('.item').css('margin-top', 0); /*reset the margin*/
  for (var i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + j).css('order', or++);
      }
    else {
      for (var j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
        $('.item').eq(nb * i + (nb - j - 1)).css('order', or++);
      }
      if (i == (nr - 1)) {
        /*we add margin+height of non-existing element*/
        $('.item:last').css('margin-top', ((nb * nr - n_t) * (80 + 10)) + "px")
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
  <div class="item">I</div>
  <div class="item">J</div>
  <div class="item">K</div>
  <div class="item">L</div>
  <div class="item">M</div>
  <div class="item">N</div>
  <div class="item">O</div>
  <div class="item">P</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with Flexbox and a bit of JavaScript (I was unable to do it with *CSS alone*):

```js
var reverseBoxes = function () {

  var flexItems = document.querySelectorAll(".child"),
      flexItemsCount = flexItems.length,
      reverseAt = flexItems.length / 2,
      breakPoint = 480;

  for (var i = reverseAt; i < flexItemsCount; i++) {
    flexItems[i].style.order = flexItemsCount - i;
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < flexItemsCount; j++) {
    if (window.innerWidth > breakPoint) {
      flexItems[j].style.width = (100 / flexItemsCount) * 2 - 2 + "%";
      flexItems[j].style.height = "auto";
    } else {
      flexItems[j].style.height = (100 / flexItemsCount) * 2 - 2 + "%";
      flexItems[j].style.width = "auto";
    }
  }

}

reverseBoxes();
window.addEventListener("resize", reverseBoxes);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  margin: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #069;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .child {
    width: 48%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">A</div>
  <div class="child">B</div>
  <div class="child">C</div>
  <div class="child">D</div>
  <div class="child">E</div>
  <div class="child">F</div>
  <div class="child">G</div>
  <div class="child">H</div>
  <div class="child">I</div>
  <div class="child">J</div>
</div>
```

Is it what you ware looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick that helps you select half of the items. Use `float:left` as default, and set `float: right` to the items which were selected as the second half.

The downside is that you'll need to define a lot of rules if you need to support a lot of items.

```css
.box{
  width: 160px;
}

.item{
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
}

/* selecting half or more items. Up to 6 */
.item:first-child:last-child,
.item:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(-n+2),
.item:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3),
.item:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(-n+4),
.item:nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(-n+5),
.item:nth-child(n+6):nth-last-child(-n+6) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
</div>
```

And the vertical scenario could be:

```css
.box {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.item {
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}


/* selecting half or more items. Up to 6 */

.item:first-child:last-child,
.item:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(-n+2),
.item:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3),
.item:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(-n+4),
.item:nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(-n+5),
.item:nth-child(n+6):nth-last-child(-n+6) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
  <div class="item">H</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AdityaGupta yes, it won't support infinite number of items, but he might need a maximum 20, and it's possible to cover it...

Comment: Nevermind, just read the comments. He is generating the rows through code. He can use 'flex-box' in his case.