# How do I return position of an element in flex wrapped row based on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried and failed to use the nearly perfect answer given here: [How to calculate the amount of flexbox items in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043684/how-to-calculate-the-amount-of-flexbox-items-in-a-row/49046973#49046973)

The answer given returns the item count only in the top row. But I'm needing to get the position of an element clicked, in any row.

For example, in the below demo, if a user clicked on the box that is highlighted in black, how would I get the value of "2" out?

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.active.item {
  outline: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid" class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item active"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I would assume a solution would not care about wrapping based on container size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```js
document.getElementById("grid").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const grid = Array.from(this.children);
  const baseOffset = grid[0].offsetTop;
  const breakIndex = grid.findIndex(item => item.offsetTop > baseOffset);
  const numPerRow = (breakIndex === -1 ? grid.length : breakIndex);
  const el = event.target;
  const el_index = [...grid].indexOf(el);
  const position = (el_index % numPerRow) + 1
  console.log(position);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Can you explain what this is doing? const el_index = [...grid].indexOf(el);

Comment: `el` is the element clicked. `el_index` is finding the index of the element in the `grid` which is the list of the elements inside grid (all divs inside it, in this case 10 items/divs). For example, if you click at element of position 10, the el_index will be 9. After that we get the remainder of the division `9 per numPerRow` if `numPerRow` is 6, the remainder is 3, but we need to add more 1 because of starting index of 0, and results 4 is position by row. Was I clear? I could explain line by line if you want to, but the first lines is just a copy from the other post you linked.

Comment: Yes, you were clear. I follow, thank you. Can I ask how to handle a slight modification? If a tile contains content, like other DIVs, how would I fire the function regardless of where IN the parent someone clicked? Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/frazzledCoder/j57u8ctq/

Comment: Yeah no problem. But that's completely another topic. It can be resolved in different ways. Here is a fiddle with two options, one pure CSS and another with javascript. https://jsfiddle.net/unLqwfc7/4/

Comment: Friend, thank you for answering even outside the scope of the original question. I learned some new things today. Thank you very much! Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

I have made explicit use of the `rowLength` of each row, `index` of each element to get the desired result. I have also removed the fixed width for `.grid` container so that you can see for other width changes. You have to refresh the page to see it working for different width. For automatic size detection you may need to add resize event handler as well. I have also added comments on the script whenever necessary to help with the logic. You can run the code here itself and the position of the element will be alerted. Let me know if you need explanation on the script part. The solution will work for any number of rows and columns. I have wrapped the entire logic inside `myFunc` just for readability regarding variable scope and all.

```js
function myFunc() {
  let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  let itemLength = items.length;
  let rowLength = 1;
  let baseOffsetTop = items[0].offsetTop;

  // find length of a single row
  for (let i = 1; i < itemLength; i++) {
    if (baseOffsetTop === items[i].offsetTop) {
      rowLength += 1;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  // event handler
  function handleClick(event) {
    for (let j = 0; j < itemLength; j++) {
      let position;
      if (items[j] === event.currentTarget && j < rowLength) {
        // position for first row elements
        position = j + 1;
        alert(`Position: ${position}`);
        break;
      } else if (items[j] === event.currentTarget && j >= rowLength) {
        if ((j + 1) % rowLength === 0) {
          // position for last elements of each row after first row
          position = rowLength;
          alert(`Position: ${position}`);
          break;
        }
        // position for rest of the row elements
        alert(`Position: ${(j+1) % rowLength}`);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // add onlick event
  Array.from(items).forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
  });
}

myFunc();
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.active.item {
  outline: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid" class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item active"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it seems logically like it should work with my situation. However, when I try and implement it nothing happens. I don't get any errors, but also no click events. I've mocked up my use case here: https://jsfiddle.net/frazzledCoder/w7a2L39e/

Comment: Sorry for delay. Since you are registering event on `div` with childs, you should use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.  `event.currentTarget` returns the element on which you have added the event listener which is `div` in your case. `event.Target` returns the element on which you have clicked which is actually on the div childs which returns the child element instead of the div element resulting in the failure of `if (items[j] === event.target && j < rowLength)` condition. I have updated the code to use `currentTarget` and that's the only thing you need to change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and response! I wish I could accept both answers, as they both approach in different ways and both have their strengths. Appreciate your help.